# How to add an active class to only one parent element with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html code for the quiz with 3 options. I would like to add the class `.active` to the `.questionItem` class.

```
<ul class="questionList">
<li class="questionItem" data-pos="0"><span class="question">Question Text</span></li>
<li class="questionItem" data-pos="1"><span class="question">Question Text</span></li>
<li class="questionItem" data-pos="2"><span class="question">Question Text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
$(this).parent().find('.questionItem').addClass('active');
```

However, this is adding active to ALL `questionItem`s. Instead I want to add this class to exactly the `questionItem` class that was clicked on.

Comment: What is `this`? It looks like you just need `$(this).addClass('active');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `this` is referring to the clicked element, so simply use the `$(this)`.  I added some click events to demonstrate how `this` works.

```js
$(".questionItem").click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="questionList">
<li class="questionItem" data-pos="0"><span class="question">Question Text</span></li>
<li class="questionItem" data-pos="1"><span class="question">Question Text</span></li>
<li class="questionItem" data-pos="2"><span class="question">Question Text</span></li>
</ul>
```

However, if you're instead trying to select the parent, you have no need for a `.find`:

```js
$(".questionItem").click(function () {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="questionList">
<li class="questionItem" data-pos="0"><span class="question">Question Text</span></li>
<li class="questionItem" data-pos="1"><span class="question">Question Text</span></li>
<li class="questionItem" data-pos="2"><span class="question">Question Text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, of course, there is a time limit that I had to wait to mark it as complete

Answer (score 2):

I think the following code will help you!

```
$('.questionItem').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```